# Filtering the array and reordering the array based on another array

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of `userAccessArray`, where each user has what all things can access based on that array i am checking with `predefinedArrayList` where all the objects comes for the application and creating a new array of objects. [Filtering it]

after that i am rearranging the order based on another array. Thats my final result.

Below is the code, its working but i thought like there should some more better way.

```js
let predefinedList = [{name: "Home Page", path:"/home"},{name: "About Page", path:"/about"}, {name: "Edit Page", path:"/edit"}, {name: "Admin Page", path:"/admin"} ]

let userAccessArray = ["editing", "aboutUs", "home"]


let userAccessList = userAccessArray.map(userAccess =>   {
    if(userAccess === "aboutUs"){
      return predefinedList[1]
    }else if(userAccess === "editing"){
      return predefinedList[2]
    }else if(userAccess === "home"){
      return predefinedList[0]
    }else if(userAccess === "adminAccess"){
      return predefinedList[3]
    }
  })
  
  
const orderOfTabs = ["Home Page", "Edit Page", "About Page", "Admin Page"]

const finalTabsArray = orderOfTabs.map(orderOfTab => userAccessList.find(userAccess => userAccess.name === orderOfTab)).filter(item => item)

console.log("finalTabsArray", finalTabsArray)
```

Comment: I think you should introduce the id property in predef list
`let predefinedList = [{name: "Home Page", path:"/home",id: 'home'}...`
and orderofTabs and userAccessArray based on id. it will make filtering easy.

`let userAccessList = predefinedList.filter(route=>userAccessArray.indexOf(route.id) !== -1)`

Comment: okay cool ! thats for the if else thing, anything more can be done for orderingOfTabs

Comment: i have an update to the post, also i am not able to add properties to the predefinedList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an `access` property for filtering `predefinedList` and an object for sorting the items with a default value for unknown `name` properties. In this case, this items are sorted at the end of the list by taking a huge value `Infinity`.

```js
const
    orderOfTabs = { "Home Page": 1, "Edit Page": 2, "About Page": 3, "Admin Page": 4, default: Infinity },
    predefinedList = [{ name: "Home Page", path:"/home", access: "home" }, { name: "About Page", path:"/about", access: "aboutUs" }, { name: "Edit Page", path:"/edit", access: "editing" }, { name: "Admin Page", path:"/admin", access: "adminAccess" }],
    userAccessArray = ["editing", "aboutUs", "home"],
    finalTabsArray = predefinedList
        .filter(({ access }) => userAccessArray.includes(access))
        .sort(({ name: a }, { name: b }) =>
            (orderOfTabs[a] || orderOfTabs.default) - (orderOfTabs[b] || orderOfTabs.default));

console.log(finalTabsArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i have updated the question. Can you check the userAccessArray and if else condition have a change in the question. Can you please update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `if..elseif` ladder, you can use the `.filter` method to generate the `userAccessList` array. See the code below.

```js
let predefinedList = [{
  name: "Home Page",
  path: "/home"
}, {
  name: "About Page",
  path: "/about"
}, {
  name: "Edit Page",
  path: "/edit"
}, {
  name: "Admin Page",
  path: "/admin"
}]

let userAccessArray = ["edit", "about", "home"]


let userAccessList = predefinedList.filter(item =>
  userAccessArray.indexOf(item.path.substr(1)) > -1)


const orderOfTabs = ["Home Page", "Edit Page", "About Page", "Admin Page"]

const finalTabsArray = orderOfTabs.map(orderOfTab => userAccessList.find(userAccess => userAccess.name === orderOfTab)).filter(item => item)

console.log("finalTabsArray", finalTabsArray)
```

Comment: thanks vivek :) for orderOfTabs, can i reduce the  finalTabsArray

Comment: but i have an update to the post , can you check the post

Comment: Regarding `orderOfTabs`, there isn't much optimization be done. Best thing you can do is to ensure `predefinedList` comes in the order that you want.

Comment: okay , i have updated the question. Can you check the userAccessArray and if else condition have a change in the question. Can you please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the predefinedList and then have easy access:

```js
let predefinedList = {
    "home": {name: "Home Page", path:"/home"}, 
    "aboutUs": {name: "About Page", path:"/about"}, 
    "editing": {name: "Edit Page", path:"/edit"}, 
    "admin": {name: "Admin Page", path:"/admin"} 
    }

let userAccessArray = ["editing", "aboutUs", "home"];

let userAccessList = userAccessArray.map(item => predefinedList[item]);

console.log(userAccessList);
```

EDIT: changed the code based on your changes in the code. As for the orderOfTabs, this can't be really optimized.

Answer (score 0):

```
let predefinedList = [{name: "Home Page", path:"/home"},{name: "About Page", path:"/about"}, {name: "Edit Page", path:"/edit"}, {name: "Admin Page", path:"/admin"} ]
const orderOfTabs = ["Home Page", "Edit Page", "About Page", "Admin Page"];

let userAccessArray = ["admin", "edit", "about", "home"]

function getUserActionList(type) {
    switch(type) {
    case 'about':
        return predefinedList[1];
    case 'home':
        return predefinedList[0];
    case 'edit':
        return predefinedList[2];
    case 'admin':
        return predefinedList[3];
  }
}

let userAccessList = userAccessArray.map(userAccess => getUserActionList(userAccess));

userAccessList.sort( function (a, b) {
    var prevV = a['name'], nextV = b['name'];
  return (orderOfTabs.indexOf(prevV) > orderOfTabs.indexOf(nextV)) ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(userAccessList)
```